# Custom scope for .NET application settings

Tags: .net, scope, settings

I can define my custom scope:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class SiteScopedSettingAttribute : SettingAttribute
{
}
```

How do I use it in the Visual Studio Settings editor (make it available in the "Scope" combobox)?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you must edit by hand the Settings.settings file opening it as an XML file and putting the text inside the Scope XML attribute.